# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 15.04 'Vivid'

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dist-upgrade

When trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 15.04:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

I get an error message:

```
An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool
```

I even found a bug report for this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1609796

but there no solution is provided.

Comment: see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](//askubuntu.com/q/91815)

Answer (score 9):

Well, the indirect route almost worked for me.
I will describe... though it did not work at the end
THat is first updating into wily version, next into xenial.
There is similar answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/892743/ubuntu-server-stuck-at-15-04-and-cannot-upgrade
In detail,

delete the content of sources.list using

```
   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

replace it with

```
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
     deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

At this point, you will have wily version of Ubuntu.
Then once again

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and you will have to type Y on questions then I got an error at restart.
What really worked is that I downloaded the Ubuntu 16 iso and it allowed me to overwrite current installation while keeping all data.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported to upgrade from 15.04 to 16.04 directly. You can upgrade from lts to lts that means from 14.04 to 16.04. If you like Adventures choose your sources.list to `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main restricted universe multiverse` and upgrade to wily 15.10 first, then you can upgrade to 16.04. But the better is way to install xenial (16.04.01) fresh after then you have save your personal Datas.

Comment: fresh install means reconfiguring the whole system, does not sound like a nice way

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections \* >  $HOME/dpkg.txt`  under 15.04. In new xenial-installation. `dpkg  --set-selections <  $HOME/dpkg.txt`  `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`  So you have your packages back.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Make use of the following command-
**sudo do-release-upgrade -d**

That worked for me.

Comment: -1 You should not recommend using `-d` flag with `do-release-upgrade` because it installs the unstable ("development") version if it works at all.

Comment: @Zanna: Thanks for the info. Really didnt knew of the above. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: You're very welcome of course.  Perhaps you could do some research and edit your answer (see my comment on the question)